# Google Analytics showing named URL for every page except the home page which only shows a forward slash

Tags: google-analytics, url, homepage, path

My main homepage URL in analytics does not have a name and is just showing as a '/':

[image]

Every other page on the site is has a name following the '/' for example '/sign-gallery. I am worried that my site set up is wrong. Can anybody advise please?

Comment: The `/` is the normal way of representing the root web directory. This is normal.